# Querying nested list in python - Issues with the query syntax

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I want to query a nested list in MongoDB using PyMongo in Python. The problem is with the query for checking the second-level(inner list) parameter value.

The structure of the collection is like this:

```
[
   {
    "name": "rahul", 
    "values": [
                {
                    "time":"2017-08-08 05:01:11"
                    "a": 5.766666666666667,
                    "b" : 3,
                    "c" : 2
                },
                {
                    "time":"2017-08-08 05:16:40"
                    "a": 5.766666666666667,
                    "b" : 3,
                    "c" : 2
                }
        ]
    },
   {
    "name": "shenoy", 
    "values": [
                {
                    "time":"2017-08-08 05:01:11"
                    "a": 1,
                    "b" : 6,
                    "c" : 8
                },
                {
                    "time":"2017-08-08 05:16:40"
                    "a": 5,
                    "b" : 8,
                    "c" : 1
                }
        ]
    }

]
```

I want all the documents with value of "c" equals 1.
The solutions I came across were like:

```
for data in db.collection_name.find({'values.c': 1})
```

However, this is not working out. I also tried solutions like `"values.$.c" : 1` and also .
Please suggest me some solution for querying this JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
collection.find_one({'values': {'$elemMatch': {'c': 1}}})
```